# Android: inflated view do not show in customed ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewgroup, inflate

I made a customed view by extending ViewGroup, my problems is:

when adding a child( addView(chileView) ) view into ViewGroup, if the child view is a inflated view, the child view will not show. but when the child view is hard-code view( like, btn = new Button(ctx) ), it will show!

The Code, not show:

```
public class EdgeSwiper extends ViewGroup{

    public EdgeSwiper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public EdgeSwiper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public EdgeSwiper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    View v;
    private void init(Context context) {
        v = View.inflate(context,R.layout.aview,null);
        this.addView(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        v.layout(a, b,  c, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you're having a problem with?